# find user's profile information with paper's user_id field?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i have 3 table in a cakephp 2 application: 
**users** :

- id
- email

**profiles** :

- id
- name
- user_id

**papers** :

- id
- title
- user_id

I will show this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| user->ID |    profile -> name   | paper -> ID | paper -> title |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|   123    |        jack          |      12     |      test1     |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|   125    |        jonn          |      15     |     mypaper    |
------------------------------------------------------------------
etc.
```

maybe user haven't any paper.
User hasOne Profile.
User hasMany Paper.

how i can do this in an action in users_controller?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need is to specify the model associations in the respective models. Save the following files in app/Model folder.

```
//User Model: User.php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class User extends AppModel
{
public $name = 'User';
public $useTable = 'users';    
public $primaryKey = 'id';
public $hasOne = array('Profile' => array(
                                          'className' => 'Profile',
                                          'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
                                          )
                       );
public $hasMany = array('Paper' => array(
                                         'className' => 'Paper',
                                         'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
                                         )
                        );
}

//Profile Model: Profile.php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Profile extends AppModel
{
public $name = 'Profile';
public $useTable = 'profiles';    
public $primaryKey = 'id';
public $belongsTo = array('User' => array(
                                           'className' => 'User',
                                           'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
                                           )
                          );
}

//Paper Model: Paper.php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Paper extends AppModel
{
public $name = 'Paper';
public $useTable = 'papers';    
public $primaryKey = 'id';
public $belongsTo = array('User' => array(
                                           'className' => 'User',
                                           'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
                                           )
                          );
}
```

You can simply find the user details along with its profile details, and all paper information through a single query:

```
$result = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array()));
```

If you want to find out user's profile details by paper's user_id, then you should write the following:

```
$result = $this->User->Paper('all', array('conditions' => array('Paper.user_id' => $user_id),
                                'recursive' => '2'));
```

You can check the output using: `pr($result);die;`

Comment: thanks @Arun, but $this->User->Paper->find(...). but don't work.

Comment: i test this and has work:
$this->User->find(...) without 'recursive' => '2' and has work.
thanks for your answer dude.

Comment: Thanks, Its always my pleasure to help. :)